# missing project after using ExternalProject_Add

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, external-project

I'm using VS2012+cmake2.8.12. My problem is that CMake failed to generate the correct path to my external project. For example:

```
Project("{...}") = "external", "external.vcxproj", "..."
```

whereas `'external.vcxproj'` should be something like `..\path\to\external.vcxproj`

Here is how I use ExternalProject_Add command:

```
ExternalProject_Add(external SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../int/external
                    CMAKE_ARGS ..
                    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../int/external/build)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building Visual Studio projects with `ExternalProject_Add` works slightly different. The whole ExternalProject module is platform-independent and unaware of the peculiarities of Visual Studio's build system. Thus just adding a VS project will not work, since ExternalProject does not know how to build it. Instead you have to specify the full command line for building the project. Something like:

```
ExternalProject_Add(external_test
    SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/external.sln /build Release /project optional_project_within_solution
    INSTALL_COMMAND "")
```

As you can see, it's quite a mess. If you just want to include an existing VS project with your CMake generated solution, consider using [`include_external_msproject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_external_msproject) instead.